# Inequality involving Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}A_1\\A_2\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{F}^{(n+m)\times n}$, with $A_1\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ and non singular, and $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. Show that

$$\lVert A^\dagger\rVert_2 \leq \lVert A_1^{-1}\rVert_2$$

How should I approach the problem?

Comment: Tiny possible typo: presumably you mean that it's in $\mathbb{F}^{(n+m)\times n}$, since you're looking at an $n\times n$ 'slice' of it?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, you're right, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\|A^\dagger\|_2^{-1}
=\min_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2
=\min_{\|x\|_2=1}\left\|\begin{bmatrix}A_1x\\A_2x\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2
\geq\min_{\|x\|_2=1}\left\|A_1x\right\|_2
=\|A_1^{-1}\|_2^{-1}
$$

---

Start with the definition:
$$
\|A^\dagger\|_2=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|A^\dagger x\|_2}{\|x\|_2}.
$$

Any such $x$ can be written in the form $x=y+z$, where 
$$y\in\mathcal{R}(A) \quad\text{and}\quad z\in\mathcal{R}(A)^\perp=\mathcal{N}(A^*)=\mathcal{N}(A^\dagger).$$
We have that $A^\dagger x=A^\dagger y+A^\dagger z=A^\dagger y$ and since $y\perp z$, $\|x\|_2^2=\|y\|_2^2+\|z\|_2^2$. The maximum is therefore attained when $z=0$. We can write $y=Aw$ for some $w$. All this given then
$$
\|A^\dagger\|_2=\max_{w\neq 0}\frac{\|A^\dagger Aw\|_2}{\|Aw\|_2}.
$$
Since the rank of $A$ is $n$, $A^\dagger A=I$, and
$$
\|A^\dagger\|_2=\max_{w\neq 0}\frac{\|w\|_2}{\|Aw\|_2}=\left(\min_{w\neq 0}\frac{\|Aw\|_2}{\|w\|_2}\right)^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Why is $\lVert A^\dagger \rVert_2^{-1} = \min_{\lVert x \rVert_2=1} \lVert Ax\rVert_2$ and $\lVert A_1^{-1}\rVert_2^{-1} = \min_{\lVert x \rVert_2=1}\lVert A_1x\rVert_2$?

Comment: @user139019 See the edit.